# How to force macro keep running even pattern is not found?

Tags: macro

I have a macro to swap text.
[image]

For single line, it's running without problem.
But if I run this macro many times and one line is empty or different pattern, it will print below error and stop.
[image]
Is there a way to force it keep running even the pattern is not found.

Comment: Could you show a sample code and the end result you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `:try` to do that ([`:h :try`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3atry)).

Here is an example (I didn't use your macro because you posted it as an image and it's not easy to copy :) )

```
let @z=':try|s/foo/bar/|catch||endtry^M'
```

(Note that `^M` should be entered with <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>)

This way `@z` will try to make the substitution and if it fails nothing will happen. For example on this buffer:

```
foo
faa
fii
foo
faa
```

Using `5@z` will substitute all of the `foo`.

Comment: The command let @z=':try|s/foo/bar/|catch||endtry' is not working.

Comment: @Fisher that's weird because it works on my system. How is it not working? Do you have an error message?

Comment: Tried the command, it reports "Error detected while processing : E488: Trailing characters.   (Not sure how to add picture to the comment.)

Comment: @Fisher I can't reproduce the error, but I noticed that my copy paste failed and that the `^M` character was missing. However I'm not sure how this could lead to a trailing characters error.

Comment: I've added `^M`, but still only first line is changed. Only working if I add `j` after the `^M`. And found another way `:silent!`.

Comment: Found another way to avoid the error. Add function in .vimrc and check if condition is satisfied, otherwise don't run the command. Like: let current_line=getline('.')
      if current_line =~ ":"

Answer (score 9):

Since you're using the `s` command, you could simply use the `e` flag. From `:help :s_flags`:

> When the search pattern fails, do not issue an error message and, in particular, continue in maps as if no error occurred.

So, each of the `s` commands in your macro would look something like:

```
:s/bar/food/e
```

Comment: Combining this with the [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15142) from above makes creating general purpose search and replace macros *much* easier!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global command with optional regex, for example:

```
:g/a\|b/norm! @z
```

The command above will run the macro "z" only on the lines that have 'a' or 'b'

TIP: when setting your macro you can use double quotes to be able to use special keys like this:

```
:let @a="iHello World\<CR>bye!\<Esc>"
```