# How to ignore a failed :g (global) command in a macro?

Tags: macro, global-command

Part of a macro I'm writing deletes any blank lines, and then does some more work (joining the expected two remaining lines and then appending to them). Simplified version:

```
let @m=':g/^$/d^MggJA ^['
```

(Where of course ^M and ^[ are the CR and ESC literals.)

However, sometimes my input doesn't include any blank lines, and I can't get the macro to proceed when the `:g` command fails:

```
Pattern not found: ^$
```

(Same happens with different message when I try `:v/./d` instead: `Pattern found in every line: .`)

I got my hopes up when I found [How to force macro keep running even pattern is not found?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15140/how-to-force-macro-keep-running-even-pattern-is-not-found/), where the answers suggest using `:try`, but this doesn't seem to work with `:g` or `:v`:

```
:let @m=':try|:g/^$/d|catch||endtry^MggJA ^['
```

If this is run on input with no blank lines, it leaves the editor in command-line mode and I have to type `endtry` to get out of it. I try adding an additional `endtry` to the macro:

```
:let @m=':try|:g/^$/d|catch||endtry^Mendtry^MggJA ^['
```

This works for input with no blank lines. But when I go back and try this on input that contains blank lines, I get

```
E603: :catch without :try
```

Is there any hope to be had here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @BLayer that you're crossing into territory where putting this into a function would be a good idea. A nice short way to suppress errors is `:silent!` (with `!`). It'll work in your macro like this:

```
let @m=':silent! g/^$/d^MggJA ^['
```

This is shorter than `try...catch`; one side effect is that it silences *any* output (errors or normal output). With `:global`, that shouldn't be a problem; elsewhere, it can be avoided via the (somewhat funny) `:silent! unsilent {cmd}` expression.

Answer (score 3):

It's at this point where you ought to consider alternatives to using a macro. For instance, a function and mapping. Off the top of my head...

```
func! DelEmptyAndStuff()
    if search('^$', 'n') != 0
        exec 'g//d'
    endif
    exec 'norm! ggJA '
endfunc

nnoremap \m :call DelEmptyAndStuff()
```

(Note: without a pattern `:global` will use the last used pattern. That's why `g//d` works here.)

Even a mapping alone with the above code stuffed in it will be easier/cleaner than the equivalent macro...

```
nnoremap \m if search('^$', 'n') != 0 \| exec 'g//d' \| endif \| norm! ggJA <CR>
```

But, okay, let's say you are "contractually bound" to use a macro. We could use a modified version of the above code...

```
let @m=":if search('^$', 'n') != 0^Mexec 'g//d'^Mendif^M^[ggJA ^["
```

Not pretty but since "the halt on error" behavior of macros probably isn't meant to be defeated...at least this works.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm enough of a noob that I'd not even considered a non-macro solution. A function is a lot more readable and presumably maintainable too.

Comment: @Owen Yep. Both those things. Cheers.